# How to remove the value label above each bar in bar chart for ios-charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Each bar has a value above it, but whenever I get too many data entries graphed, these values are spilling over into each other and making themselves unreadable. The only way to edit these that I could find was setting them to either above or below each bar. However I would like to hide them completely. How do I do this in swift?

Answer (score 19):

There is a method called setDrawValues which allows you to enable or disable the label text. Here an example in Swift with LineChart:

```
xValues = ["1","2"]
yValues = [54.0, 42.0]

var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

for i in 0..<xValues.count {
   let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: yvalues[i], xIndex: i)
   dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}

let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "YourData")
let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: xValues, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)

// this disables the display of the labels - be sure to apply it to your LineChartData object
lineChartData.setDrawValues(false)
```

**Edit:** For sure in your case you can use this method also for your BarChartData object.

Documentation can be found here (ios-charts is based on MPAndroidChart and therefore has more or less the same functionality): https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.2.3/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/ChartData.html#setDrawValues(boolean)

Comment: how to enable the setDrawValue for specific bar like
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979926/how-to-achieve-trackball-on-charts-in-swift-3x
but this is in swift 3 how can i achieve the same thing in swift 2 ??

Answer (score 9):

You can disable the labels by adding the following line;

```
lineData.setDrawValues(false)
```

Comment: How to add TrackBall and edit label above BarCharts in Charts swift2 ??
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979926/how-to-achieve-trackball-on-charts-in-swift-3x

Answer (score 5):

You can use drawValuesEnabled as below :

```
let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: nil)
chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 4):

This does the trick for Swift 4

```
yourChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift3 following line can do the job:

```
chartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score -1):

Set this flag to True or False

```
_chart.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: This doesn't hide the labels completely..this draws them below the top of bars