# iOS Charts remove values on the bar of the bar chart

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart, ios-charts

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts
[image]

How to hide the values which are shown on each bar.
My code is as below

```
func setUpChartView(){
    viewGraphContent.delegate = self
    viewGraphContent.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    viewGraphContent.chartDescription?.enabled = true
    viewGraphContent.dragEnabled = false
    viewGraphContent.setScaleEnabled(false)
    viewGraphContent.highlightFullBarEnabled = true
    viewGraphContent.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    viewGraphContent.drawBordersEnabled = true
    viewGraphContent.borderColor = UIColor.white
    viewGraphContent.borderLineWidth = 1
    viewGraphContent.legend.enabled = false
  }
```

Comment: That data you are pointing is of BarChartDataEntry. Can you show your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193312/how-to-remove-the-value-label-above-each-bar-in-bar-chart-for-ios-charts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add following line of code where you setup sets of chart to fix your issue:

```
var set = BarChartDataSet(values: yVals, label: "Data Set")        
set.drawValuesEnabled = false       // Set this property to false to hide all values

let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set)
yourChartView.data = data
```

This code will hide all values above bar chart. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: Happy to help you. :)